# Segfault when I want to initialize a 2d array of chars with its address

Tags: arrays, c, segmentation-fault

I'm working on a project and I need to modify a 2d array in another function than where I create it. However, I'm getting segfaults by trying to do this and I don't understand the problem.

Here is the code of what I'm trying to do:

```
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <stdio.h>

void    test(char ***tab)
{
    *tab = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 2);
    *tab[0] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
    *tab[0][0] = 't';
    printf("%c\n", *tab[0][0]);
    *tab[0][1] = 'e';
    printf("%c\n", *tab[0][1]);
    *tab[0][2] = 's';
    *tab[0][3] = 't';
    *tab[0][4] = '\0';
    tab[1] = NULL;
}

int main()
{
    char **tab1;
    char **tab2;
    tab1 = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 2);
    tab1[0] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
    tab1[0][0] = 't';
    tab1[0][1] = 'e';
    tab1[0][2] = 's';
    tab1[0][3] = 't';
    tab1[0][4] = '\0';
    tab1[1] = NULL;
    printf("tab1 %s\n", tab1[0]);

    test(&tab2);
    printf("%s\n", tab2[0]);
}
```

I compile my code with:

```
gcc -fsanitize=address test.c
```

and here is the output

```
tab1 test
t
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==12145==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000000 (pc 0x0000004c22c8 bp 0x7ffc58e533d0 sp 0x7ffc58e532c0 T0)
==12145==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
==12145==Hint: address points to the zero page.
    #0 0x4c22c7 in test (/home/user42/Bureau/a.out+0x4c22c7)
    #1 0x4c2aaa in main (/home/user42/Bureau/a.out+0x4c2aaa)
    #2 0x7fc4aebc4b96 in __libc_start_main /build/glibc-2ORdQG/glibc-2.27/csu/../csu/libc-start.c:310
    #3 0x41aaa9 in _start (/home/user42/Bureau/a.out+0x41aaa9)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV (/home/user42/Bureau/a.out+0x4c22c7) in test
==12145==ABORTING
```

As you can see, the `tab1` doesn't cause any segfaults when I initialize it, but `tab2` does after initializing the first character. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the unary `*` operator associates more loosely than the `[]` operator, so you need to add parentheses in most of the places in `test`.  The following fixes it.

Also note that `tab[1] = NULL;` was missing the `*` altogether.  It needed to be `(*tab)[1] = NULL;` (see below).  This is an important fix, since without it the code is subject to undefined behavior:

```
void    test(char ***tab)
{
    *tab = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 2);
    (*tab)[0] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
    (*tab)[0][0] = 't';
    printf("%c\n", (*tab)[0][0]);
    (*tab)[0][1] = 'e';
    printf("%c\n", (*tab)[0][1]);
    (*tab)[0][2] = 's';
    (*tab)[0][3] = 't';
    (*tab)[0][4] = '\0';
    (*tab)[1] = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it works now!  however I don't understand how the parentheses fix this issue ? what do you mean by "the unary * operator associates more loosely than the [] operator"

Comment: What I mean is that `*x[i]` is equivalent to `*(x[i])`, as opposed to `(*x)[i]`.  The operator groupings are different.  With `*(x[i])`, it first adds `i` to `x`.  With `(*x)[i]`, it first dereferences `x`, *then* adds `i`.  The two behaviors are very different.  The first is equivalent to `*(*(x+i))`.  The second is equivalent to `*((*x)+i)`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an operator precedence problem:

```c
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <stdio.h>

void    test(char ***tab)
{
    *tab = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 2);
    (*tab)[0] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
    (*tab)[0][0] = 't';
    printf("%c\n", (*tab)[0][0]);
    (*tab)[0][1] = 'e';
    printf("%c\n", (*tab)[0][1]);
    (*tab)[0][2] = 's';
    (*tab)[0][3] = 't';
    (*tab)[0][4] = '\0';
    (*tab)[1] = NULL;
}

int main()
{
    char **tab1;
    char **tab2;
    tab1 = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 2);
    tab1[0] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
    tab1[0][0] = 't';
    tab1[0][1] = 'e';
    tab1[0][2] = 's';
    tab1[0][3] = 't';
    tab1[0][4] = '\0';
    tab1[1] = NULL;
    printf("tab1 %s\n", tab1[0]);

    test(&tab2);
    printf("%s\n", tab2[0]);
}
```

You can compile with `-ggdb3` to get more information in your sanitizer stack traces which will help you debug these sorts of problems:

```
$ gcc foo.c -ggdb3
$ valgrind ./a.out
==121594== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==121594== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==121594== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==121594== Command: ./a.out
==121594== 
tab1 test
t
==121594== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==121594==    at 0x109220: test (foo.c:10)
==121594==    by 0x109348: main (foo.c:32)
==121594== 
==121594== Invalid write of size 1
==121594==    at 0x109220: test (foo.c:10)
==121594==    by 0x109348: main (foo.c:32)
==121594==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

`Use of uninitialised value of size 8 at 0x109220: test (foo.c:10)` tells you precisely where the problem is.

As [Tom mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68214058/6243352), `tab[1]` is an out of bounds access leading to undefined behavior. You can use `(*tab)[1] = NULL;` here -- first dereference the `***` pointer to get a `**`, then set offset 1 (conceptually, row 1) to NULL.

As an aside, don't forget to release your memory after use, and `sizeof(char)` is always 1 so you don't need it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! `(*tab)tab[1] = NULL` should work tho?

Comment: No problem, thanks for the question. No, that won't work and doesn't look syntactically valid. Do you mean `(*tab)[1] = NULL`?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant now I'm good thank you very much!